# Javascript/React: How to detect `await` call and setState accordingly?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2016

I have a function `foo` that may or may not invoke several asynchronous requests in order to cache a token:

```
async foo() {
    let token = this._token;

    if(!token) {
        token = await this.getTokenFromStorage();
    }        

    if(Tokens.isExpired(this._token) {
        this._token = await Tokens.refresh(this._token);
    } else {
        this._token = token;
    }

    return this._token;
}
```

Now, I want the React comoponent calling `foo` to have some logic like:

1. Call foo()
2. If foo has cached token, `setState{isLoading: false}`
3. Otherwise, `setState{ isLoading: true }`, and wait for async operation to complete. Call `setState{ isLoading: false }` after async op is done and returns the newly cached token...

Pretty lost as to how to go about doing this though...Help appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you can set your `isLoading` state to `true` at the start of your `foo` and to `false` at the end.

Comment: Why do you care if it retrieves from the cache or not? Its much easier to just always set loading to true before calling foo.

Comment: I feel like this would trigger un-necessary re-renders from 'React' because I would be setting `isLoading: true` even if the token was cached, then setting it back to false in the same method immediately...seems wasteful.

Comment: @Cod3Citrus Well your alternative is to expose the internals of your function to a higher level which defeats your transparent caching attempt.  Of course you can do it but you will couple your function to the presentation layer.  Part of the fun of react is writing inefficent code that gets rendered. Keep in mind just because react re renders doesnt mean you get a dom refresh which is the slow part.

Comment: is foo outside of the component that you want to change its state?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure how you have structured your application, however perhaps the following provides you with some clues on how you can achieve `loading` state changes in relation to your `async foo()` method:

```
  class YourReactComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {       
      // Set the initial default state of your component. 
      // token added as an optional extra for the purpose of this example
      this.state = {
        loading : false,
        token : ''
      }
    }

    async getTokenFromStorage() {
      // ... your implementation
    }

    // Modifed version of your foo method
    async foo(token) {

        // Condition to determine if loading state should be updated
        // We will use this to avoid redundant setState calls
        const shouldLoad = !token || Tokens.isExpired(token);

        // Check to see if we need to update loading state
        if(shouldLoad) {
          this.setState({ loading : true })
        }

        if(!token) {
          token = await this.getTokenFromStorage();
        }        
        else if(Tokens.isExpired(token)) {
          token = await Tokens.refresh(token);
        }

        // If loading state was previously updated, reset it
        if(shouldLoad) {
          this.setState({ loading : false })
        }

        return token;
    }

    // A render method I have created to demonstrate the concepts at hand
    render() {

      const { loading, token } = this.state

      return (<div>
          <button onClick={ async () => console.log(`Got this token: ${ this.foo(token) }`) }>load token</button>
          <p>{ loading ? 'Loading' : 'Ready' }</p>
        </div>)
    }
  }
```

The key concept to keep in mind are:

- the `setState(..)` method is avalible from within `React.Component` instances
- calling `setState(..)` is used to update internal state for the component
- calling `setState(..)` also causes a re-render of the component (and affected children).

For more on the `.setState()` method, see [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Hey @Dacre thanks for the response. I was intending to figure out if there was away to avoid setting isLoading to true if the token was already cached though.

Comment: Hey you are welcome - thanks for the clarification. I have just updated my answer. Does that help answer your initial query?